# How to check if the other user has blocked me in XMPPFramework?

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I am using XEP-0016 ( privacy list ) for blocking users, How do i figure out if a user has blocked me?

Comment: Did you find a way to do that?

Comment: @GabyFitcal No. I kept a list of blocked users in my server to get around this problem.